# How can I change multiple line from txt

Tags: java

I have a text file with letters up and I want to make them lower letters. It is the code but it becomes only the last line

```
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\j.txt"));

         String line;
         while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
         {
            blig=line.toUpperCase();
          }     

     try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\j.txt"))) {
         writer.write(blig);
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are traversing through the whole file but just storing the last line. In order to get all the lines, you need to store all the lines you are reading, convert them to uppercase, then write them back to the file:

```
List<String> upper = new ArrayList<>();
try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\j.txt")))
{
    String line;
    while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
    {
        // upper.add(line.toUpperCase()); // if you need upper case
        upper.add(line.toLowerCase());    // if you need lower case
    }     
}

try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\j.txt")))
{
    for(String str : upper) 
    {
        writer.write(str);
        writer.newLine(); // remove if not needed.
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are writing only the last line while you are not concatenating all the result. 
replace the while statement by

```
 blig += line.toUpperCase() + "\\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\j.txt"));
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\lowerJ.txt"));

String line;
while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    writer.write(line.toLowerCase());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to lower the case of characters, then why use to Uper?

`blig=line.toUpperCase();`

**It sould be bling=line.toLowerCase();**